# Use only memory cache and disable disk cache

Tags: android, android-glide

I am prefetching images with Glide downloadOnly(), unfortunately preload() wasn't working. Is there a way to only have a memory cache and not use the disk since the images will be invalidate after a few hours? Right now I am just using `DiskStrategy.SOURCE`.